# .on("change",function(){} don't call function inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    $("#text").on("change",function(){
        var id =  $(this).val();
        if(id!= ""){
            $('#test').rules('remove',  'required');
        }else{
            $('#test').rules('add',  'required');
        }
        debugger;
        SetIndicator(id);           
    });

    function SetIndicator(id){ do something..}
</script>
```

The problem is when I change "#text" it don't call SetIndicator(id), but when I refresh page SetIndicator(id) work nomarly

For jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/76thdqcp/

Comment: How and where are you setting SetIndicator function? You're losing the scope, that's the problem. In order for us to help you we need the rest of the code.

Comment: try and put `$("#text").on("change",function(){` into a `document.ready` block.

Comment: @gugateider I ready edit qustion

Comment: Does it call the rest of the 'change' code?  (eg does it hit the debugger)?  Or is it *just* the SetIndicator() that's not being called?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in fiddle or stacksnippet?

Comment: Probably just JavaScript being JavaScript and it requiring OP to define the function before it is used.

Comment: @freedomn-m just only SetIndicator(id) that's don't call

Comment: @Glubus and that's how JS has worked since? (or rather how it hasn't worked since, maybe it did in the '90s)

Comment: Ok. do you get a console error instead? Because if you reached the debugger line (as you've stated), then the next line should execute no problem once you tell the browser to continue. The only reason it might not is if it causes a runtime error.

Comment: It's seems problem in your attribute "rules" at `$('#test').rules('remove',  'required');` And `$('#test').rules('add',  'required');`. Can you look into console and let us know what issue are you getting? Additionally, comment the rules code and let us know further code are working fine or not.

Comment: Then you either have a console error you're not telling us about or this is not all of your code.  Your best bet is to edit a snippet (one of the buttons on the edit question toolbar) that demonstrates/recreates the problem as there is nothing wrong with the code as presented.   Have a read of [mcve] (specifically verifiable)

Comment: Please check the console. (Ctrl+Shift+i in Chrome > console tab)

Comment: Also `.rules` is not a built-in jquery function, so you are including something other than just jquery to get this to work - try your code with those lines commented in the first instance.

Comment: Or `#text` is being added/updated/cloned dynamically which is why it works when you load the page but not otherwise.  But then the rest of your change event wouldn't fire, which you say it does.

Comment: on the console, it not show any error. I already add jsfiddle in the question

Comment: your JSFiddle would never work because you didn't include jQuery. Did you even check the console?? There was a clear error. https://jsfiddle.net/76thdqcp/1/ will at least execute

Comment: Anyway in that fiddle, you don't have any element with id "test" on which to execute a change event, so the event will never fire. Your select box's id is ddlPositionActing. Once we fix that... https://jsfiddle.net/76thdqcp/2/ ...then we run into the error (in the console) that ".rules()" is not defined. I don't know where the code comes from for that method so I can't help you with adding that. However if we temporarily remove that bit of code... https://jsfiddle.net/76thdqcp/3/ ...then the setIndicator method works correctly. Are you certain you are really checking your console properly?

Comment: @ADyson Sry to hear that I just us fiddle for the first time I use it. It has a lot of code in the project I try to fix it from the previous developer

Comment: Ok well I appreciate that's not an easy task, but it's hard for us to help you any further. Based on your JSFiddle I've shown you the problem(s) you need to fix. If that JSFiddle isn't representative of your real code then there's nothing more we can do - we cannot see your real code. The errors found are quite simple - I suggest you maybe take some time to improve your jQuery / JavaScript skills if you are not understanding what is happening.

Comment: Ok, now I solve this bug I change rules to be prop also I change a lot of code in question next I need to fix another bug. Thank you for everyone I will learn more about JS because I mostly work with C#, my JS skill is so poor

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the changed-event only gets fired after the focus of an textinput gets 'off'. Changing your code to the keyup-event could solve your issue.

```js
$("#text").on("keyup", function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  if (id) {
    //$('#test').rules('remove', 'required');
  } else {
    //$('#test').rules('add', 'required');
  }
  SetIndicator(id);
});

function SetIndicator(id) {
  console.log('id', id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#text").change(function(){
    var id =  $(this).val();
    if(id!= ""){
        $('#text').attr('style',  'color:red');
    }else{
        $('#text').attr('style',  'color:yellow');
    }
    SetIndicator(id);           
});

function SetIndicator(id){
  console.log(id); 
  $("#test").html("Its working");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="text" />
<div id="test"></div>
```

try below code.

```js
 $("#text").change(function(){
    var id =  $(this).val();
    if(id!= ""){
        $('#text').attr('style',  'color:red');
    }else{
        $('#text').attr('style',  'color:yellow');
    }
    SetIndicator(id);           
});

function SetIndicator(id){
  alert("hi"); $("#test").html("Its working");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="text" />
<div id="test"></div>
```

May it helps you.

Comment: A better answer would explain _why_ it would help, and also what has changed